# How to chain multiple click events on same element in JQuery?

Tags: jquery, chaining

I want to have an event fire on one click of an element, and then a different event on a second click of the same element. I've attached a demo link below. The problem is that the events are being chained so that one click runs through to the last event without waiting for the second click. I'm sorry if this is a duplicate, but I cannot find the same issue on this board.

I probably haven't worded the question very well, and I'm sure I'm going to get into trouble for it...

```
$(function(){
l $('.box')
      .click(function() {
        $(this).removeClass('red'
                        ).addClass('black');
      })
      .click(function() {
        $(this).removeClass('black'
                        ).addClass('blue');
      });
});`
```

http://jsfiddle.net/MEFNG/1/

Comment: Do you want the click events to toggle or do you only want each of them to run once?

Comment: I think you need one event handler with different conditions: In the example the condition would be: if($(this).hasClass('...')) {...} and so on.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

http://jsfiddle.net/lollero/MEFNG/3/

html:

```
<div class="box red"></div>
```

css:

```
div.box {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
}
.red {background:red}
.black {background:black}
.blue {background:blue}
```

jQuery:

```
$(function(){

    $('.box').on("click", function() {

        var box = $(this);

        if ( box.hasClass('red') ) {
            box.removeClass('red').addClass('black');
        }
        else if ( box.hasClass('black') ) {
            box.removeClass('black').addClass('blue');
        }
        else if ( box.hasClass('blue') ) {
            box.removeClass('blue').addClass('red');
        }

    });

});
```

Answer (score 3):

use delegation for best performance in this case:

```
$('.box').parent()
.on('click', '.red', function() {
  $(this).removeClass('red').addClass('black');
})
.on('click', '.black', function() {
  $(this).removeClass('black').addClass('blue');
});
```

Of course the syntax could be much better. I use similar to yours to give you a better picture.

Comment: Thanks Eru. I'll give this method a try too. My syntax was just a quick example to show what I wanted, not the actual syntax I'll be using on my site.

Answer (score 0):

Try this if you want something more dynamic. By storing a count you can add as many colors as you want and it will work just fine:

```
var classes = ['red','green','yellow','blue'];
$('.box').click(function() {
  var $this = $(this),
      count = $this.data('count') || 0;
  $this.data('count', count >= classes.length-1 ? 0 : count+1);
  $this.removeClass(classes.join(' ')).addClass(classes[count]);
});
```

**Demo:** http://jsbin.com/adoqan/1/edit

Comment: I was about to suggest perhaps adding and removing the classes of a child element of `.box` that way you wouldn't have to worry about removing the class ( e.g. http://jsfiddle.net/lollero/MEFNG/5/ ). Well, what you did works too. You got my vote. **Your jsbin link is not up to date.**

Comment: Don't mean to flood your answer with comments, but I figured that if we want to go dynamic... we should go deeper! http://jsfiddle.net/lollero/MEFNG/7/

Comment: Yeah `data` is nice for anything but I it would be semantic with colors but maybe not with other kinds of stuff...dunno

Comment: My motto is 'Semantic.. schmemantic...'. || Remember when I said something about flooding? Forgot to change 1 number in the code, so: http://jsfiddle.net/lollero/MEFNG/8/

Answer (score 0):

Try: http://jsfiddle.net/yBdBp/

```
var classes = ['red','blue','black'];
$('.box div').click(function () {
  $(this).each(function(){
  this.className = classes[($.inArray(this.className, classes)+1)%classes.length];
 });
});
```

With html:

```
<div class="box">
   <div class="red"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: I like the use of the array. The example I originally gave if for 3 coloured boxes, but I will be using the code to cycle through 5 sprites. The array makes more sense.